# Same page behaves differently when viewed on beta site vs production site

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, asp-classic

I have a page /include/redirector.asp

The beta and www are both websites hosted on the same physical server

servername xxx
OS windows 2003
IIS 6

This file exists on both my beta and production site.  Here are the contents of the file.

```
<%
If InStr(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"),Application("subdomain")) = 0  Then
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently" 
Response.AddHeader "Location",lcase("http://" & Application("subdomain") & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
End if
%>
```

- If you navigate to http://beta.sc-pa.com/include/redirector.asp you will see a blank page. <-- **this is the correct output.**
- If you navigate to http://www.sc-pa.com/include/redirector.asp you get the `internet explorer cannot display this page`, error.

What could be different between the configuration in these two sites to cause this issue?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some like [Live Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)  for firefox.

```
http://www.sc-pa.com/include/redirector.asp
GET /include/redirector.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sc-pa.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://serverfault.com/questions/239249/same-page-behaves-differently-when-viewed-on-beta-site-vs-production-site
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSCQSSBBD=ADHGDHICJHBOHKAIPKGCCNIC



HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 23 Feb 2011 16:45:29 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Location: http://wwwwww.sc-pa.com/include/redirector.asp
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: private
```

Look at the Location its trying to redirect me to: `http://wwwwww.sc-pa.com/include/redirector.asp`.  So you need to fix your code.  But that's a question for stackoverflow, not server fault.  But you're adding subdomain (which I assume is "www"), to HTTP_HOST which already contains the www.

Perhaps you should use HTTP_HOST instead of SERVER_NAME in the if clause.  Either way, print out all those variables and really think about what you want to happen.

Comment: Why would it work on one server and not the other?

Comment: Change the script to print out all of those values you're using.  If you post them, we may be able to help.